# Trying to implement a MethodArgumentResolver on exisiting web service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We currently have an endpoint with this code:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/generated/v1_0", localPart = "ContactInsertRequest")
    public @ResponsePayload ContactInsertResponse handleInsert(@RequestPayload ContactInsertRequest request, MessageContext context) {}
```

However, we need to use a custom data type, such that the signature would be:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/generated/v1_0", localPart = "ContactInsertRequest")
    public @ResponsePayload ContactInsertResponse handleInsert(@RequestPayload ContactInsertRequest request, LoginContextDO loginContext) {}
```

I implemented a MethodArgumentResolver to return LoginContextDO and added the folliwng into the spring config:

```
<bean id="defaultMethodEndPointAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <!-- must list all resolvers if declaring a endpoint adapter -->
            <bean class="com.ps.ws.endpoint.interceptor.LoginContextResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MessageContextMethodArgumentResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, its not working, I keep getting the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [public com.predictivesolutions.schema.generated.v1_0.ContactInsertResponse com.ps.ws.endpoint.v1.ContactServiceEndPoint.handleInsert(com.predictivesolutions.schema.generated.v1_0.ContactInsertRequest,com.dbo2.pipeline.authentication.LoginContextDO)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpointAdapter(MessageDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:232)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:292)
```

I think I am missing something small, but cannot figure out what to do here.  UIf I remove the defaultMethodEndpointAdapter and put back the MessageConext parameter, the webservice works fine.  Do I need to annotate the LoginContextDo parameter somehow?